# sp_help_jobhistory WITH RESULT SETS error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

## sql server 2012

I have a procedure to wrap the output from sp_help_jobhistory. The stored procedure executes without an issue, but returns error when executing this:

```
SET FMTONLY OFF
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql = N'exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobhistory_with_results'
GO
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
Msg 11512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 3]
The metadata could not be determined because the statement 'EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobhistory 
        @job_id
        ,@job_name
        ,@step_id
        ,@sql_message_id
        ,@sql' in procedure 'sp_help_jobhistory_with_results' is not compatible with the statement 'EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobhistory 
        @job_id
        ,@job_name
        ,@step_id
        ,@sql_message_id
        ,@sql' in procedure 'sp_help_jobhistory_with_results'.
```

What am I doing wrong?
Here is the code

```
use msdb
go


create proc [dbo].[sp_help_jobhistory_with_results]
@job_id                 uniqueidentifier=null
,@job_name              sysname=null
,@step_id               int=null
,@sql_message_id        int=null
,@sql_severity          int=null
,@start_run_date        int=null
,@end_run_date          int=null
,@start_run_time        int=null
,@end_run_time          int=null
,@minimum_run_duration  int=null
,@run_status            int=null
,@minimum_retries       int=null
,@oldest_first          int=0
,@server                nvarchar(30)=null
,@mode                  varchar(7)='SUMMARY'
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@mode <>'SUMMARY' and (@job_name is not null or @step_id is not null))
    BEGIN
        -- returns 17 columns
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobhistory 
        @job_id
        ,@job_name
        ,@step_id
        ,@sql_message_id
        ,@sql_severity
        ,@start_run_date
        ,@end_run_date
        ,@start_run_time
        ,@end_run_time
        ,@minimum_run_duration
        ,@run_status
        ,@minimum_retries
        ,@oldest_first
        ,@server
        ,@mode
        WITH RESULT SETS
        ( 
            (
            instance_id         int
            ,job_id             uniqueidentifier
            ,job_name           sysname
            ,step_id            int
            ,step_name          sysname
            ,sql_message_id     int
            ,sql_severity       int
            ,[message]          nvarchar(1024)
            ,run_status         int
            ,run_date           int
            ,run_time           int
            ,run_duration       int
            ,operator_emailed   nvarchar(20)
            ,operator_netsent   nvarchar(20)
            ,operator_paged     nvarchar(20)
            ,retries_attempted  int
            ,[server]           nvarchar(30)
            )
        )
    END
    -- returns 11 columns
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobhistory 
        @job_id
        ,@job_name
        ,@step_id
        ,@sql_message_id
        ,@sql_severity
        ,@start_run_date
        ,@end_run_date
        ,@start_run_time
        ,@end_run_time
        ,@minimum_run_duration
        ,@run_status
        ,@minimum_retries
        ,@oldest_first
        ,@server
        ,@mode
        WITH RESULT SETS
        ( 
            (
            job_id              uniqueidentifier
            ,job_name           sysname
            ,run_status         int
            ,run_date           int
            ,run_time           int
            ,run_duration       int
            ,operator_emailed   nvarchar(20)
            ,operator_netsent   nvarchar(20)
            ,operator_paged     nvarchar(20)
            ,retries_attempted  int
            ,[server]           nvarchar(30)
            )
        )
    END 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

The `METADATA` from your `sp_help_jobhistory_with_results` can't be determined without using `WITH RESULT SETS`, just as you did in your main procedure. Use this instead (you'll have to fill in the columns)

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql = N'exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobhistory_with_results with result sets ((Col1 datatype, Col2 datatype, etc....))'
```

Comment: I followed the sample here [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlagent/2012/07/12/workaround-sql-server-2012-openrowset-on-sp_help_job-throws-the-metadata-could-not-be-determined/](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlagent/2012/07/12/workaround-sql-server-2012-openrowset-on-sp_help_job-throws-the-metadata-could-not-be-determined/)
It doesn't need to specify `WITH RESULT SETS`

Comment: Ok @ToDo but it didn't work right? Did you try using with result sets?

Comment: The example in the link mentioned above works without specifying `WITH RESULT SETS`.
Your suggestion works for mine. I wonder what's the difference between mine and his.

Answer (score 0):

The system Stored procedure **sp_describe_first_result_set**  `Raises an error if the Database Engine cannot determine the metadata for the first query that will be executed by performing a static analysis.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx

I have not used this stored procedure before, so I don't know why you need to run it. I don't see any evidence that it was designed to be run against a stored procedure. http://stevestedman.com/2013/04/t-sql-2012-procedure-sp_describe_first_result_set/

Comment: I followed the example here [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlagent/2012/07/12/workaround-sql-server-2012-openrowset-on-sp_help_job-throws-the-metadata-could-not-be-determined/](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlagent/2012/07/12/workaround-sql-server-2012-openrowset-on-sp_help_job-throws-the-metadata-could-not-be-determined/)
sp_describe_first_result_set returns the metadata for the first possible result set of the Transact-SQL batch. And that's the reason i used it.